# Measuring spin angular momentum of electron

Tags: quantum-spin, measurements, quantum-measurements

Suppose that I have an electron. This electron has spin $\frac12$ and a spin angular momentum vector $S$. Now, when we choose a measurement axis in some direction, the spin of the electron along the measurement axis is either $\frac12\hbar$ or $-\frac12\hbar$. This number is also the value of the projection of $S$ on the measurement axis.

However, when we choose the measurement axis randomly, there is some probability that the measurement axis is perpendicular to $S$. But then we would measure spin zero. How can we resolve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean? The measurement outcomes of any chosen axis are $\pm 1/2$.

Comment: But how can the vector S have nonzero value for any axis on which we project it? That is impossible for a vector in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is that the "spin angular momentum vector" $S$ is not a **vector**, but a quantum object. It is absolutely not an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ! Instead, upon choosing a particular basis, that is a particular axis of measurement, it is a normalized vector of $\mathbb{C}^2$. The two components, modulus squared, give you the probability of measuring the spin in the $\pm \hbar / 2$ state respectively.

If you prepare the spin to have spin $\uparrow$ in the $x$ direction, the state can be written in the $z$ basis as: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |\uparrow\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |\downarrow\rangle$. These are two perpendicular directions, so if it was a classical 3D vector, you would be right: you would get zero. However it is not the case for a quantum object. If you measure it, you will get a spin up or down with probability $1/2$: there is no other outcome possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the difference between the result of an individual measurement versus the mean value (or the expectation value) of many measurements.

A famous grandad-riddle which gets the point across: do you, my human reader, have more or fewer than the average number of arms? Your instinctive answer is almost certainly that you have two arms, like almost everyone else, which is exactly the average. But "two arms" is the *mode* of the distribution, the value which occurs *most often*. People with zero or one arms are rare, but they outnumber people with three or more arms. So the *mean* number of arms on a human person is a non-integer value which is slightly smaller than two. No one has exactly the average number of arms.

An electron's spin about a random axis has expectation value zero, even though any *particular* electron must have spin $±\hbar/2$.

Comment: I agree that the average value of many measurements will be zero, but that is not the question

Comment: The question is why particular electrons can not have actual spin zero for some axes

Comment: Because the eigenvalues of the spin operator $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{S}$ representing the spin in the  direction of an arbitrary unit vector $\vec{n} \in \mathbf{R}^3$ are only $\pm \hbar/2$.